# generate sql backups or dumps for specific tables

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, database-backups

I need to generate either backups or data dumps for about 30 tables.  I want to generate a file of some sort that contains the data for these tables and transfer them to a different system.  Each table has 3.8-4.5 million rows.  also a large number of these rows have columns with text that has newline characters which need to be handled correctly.

I'm using `Sql Server 2012 and have SQL Server Management Studio`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  and I can clarify any information that is missing.

## # # # update

I have tried `SQL Server Management Studio's` `Generate Scripts` capability, which does appear to handle the newline characters, however There is another issue.  In some of the fields the text is similar to "something blah \".  that slash causes a problem with the script that gets generated, because the `Generate Scripts` process wraps that text in `''`  and with `\'` it basically escapes the single quote which corrupts the remaining data from the perspective of the external user creating a new database from this data.

I have also tried to generate flat files via `SQL Server Management Studio's` `Import/Export wizard` and this doesn't appear to handle the newline characters correctly which would corrupt the remaining data from the perspective of the external user creating a new database from this data.

Comment: Do you need an sql or can you also do this by hand? SQL Server Management Studio offers an import/export assistant to archive this. It could just be the easiest way for you.

Comment: Is the other system also using SQL Server?

Comment: I am unaware of what the other system is.  i would assume `SQL Server`.  also `SQL Server Management Studio's` options for their import/export, or generate scripts will either fail, or cause problems when taking the content and reading it into the other external database source.  this is due to the `newlines`, the `'\'` and other unique characters that are found in the text contents for these tables.